# Android - setting RecyclerView GridLayoutManager columns width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm using a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`, but as I have to specify how many columns I will be using, it divides all the columns width equally, and therefore, my `RecyclerView` messes up as on the picture below.

[image: .]

As you can see, every item has a fixed width and not a wrap_content as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want each chip to have enough width to wrap its content, and you do not want every chip in a given column to have the same width.

If so, you probably do not want to use `GridLayoutManager`. Essentially no matter what you do, it will still wind up defining some fixed column width (though you can set it up so that different columns have different widths). I believe a better choice would be `FlexboxLayoutManager`.

`FlexboxLayout` is a library from Google that allows you to specify a set of items and have them lay themselves out, wrapping as necessary. Find details here: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout